# Talend : How to get a list of nested loop with tExtractXMLField

Tags: xml, talend

I have this xml :

```
<listUsers xsi:type="UserBean">         
           <ax224:firstName>myFirstName</ax224:firstName>
           <ax224:mail>me@gmail.com</ax224:mail>
           <ax224:name>myName</ax224:name>
           <ax224:listSkill xsi:type="ax224:AgentSkillBean">
              <ax224:id>DEMO</ax224:id>
              <ax224:level>3</ax224:level>
           </ax224:listSkill>
           <ax224:listSkill xsi:type="ax224:AgentSkillBean">
              <ax224:id>CAMPAIGN_1</ax224:id>
              <ax224:level>3</ax224:level>
           </ax224:listSkill>
           <ax224:listSkill xsi:type="ax224:AgentSkillBean">
              <ax224:id>CHAT</ax224:id>
              <ax224:level>3</ax224:level>
           </ax224:listSkill>
</ax224:listUsers>
<listUsers xsi:type="UserBean"> 
...  
</ax224:listUsers> 
<listUsers xsi:type="UserBean"> 
...  
</ax224:listUsers>
```

I have to create each user in another application with those results. But i need to filter on the skills (for exemple if the user have the skill "CHAT" i need to give the corresponding role in the user that i will create in the other application).
Problem is : i don"t know how to get the skill list with my tExtractXMLField.
If i loop on the listUsers node, i don't know how to get his skills, and if i loop on the listSkill node, i get the same user as many time as the skill he have, so my job will try to create the same user many times.
I would like to have a list of skills and so in my tXMLMap i can say something like "listSkills.contains("CHAT")?true:false" but i don't know how to  get this list...
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, looping on the listSkill and then aggregate the rows with tAggregateRow component.
Thx anyway